# delete photo script gives errors in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, gallery

hi guys im trying to create a ajax delete script for my gallery but it doesn't seem to be deleting, instead it gives the following errors.

```
Warning: Division by zero in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/others/delete_photo.php on line 20

Warning: unlink(): No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/others/delete_photo.php on line 20
```

the delete script is  as follows:

```
<?php
require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/project/includes/dbconfig.inc.php';
$session=  htmlentities($_SESSION['uname']);
$sess_uname=  stripslashes($session);
$id0=  htmlentities($_POST['id']);
$id= stripslashes($id0);
$sql="DELETE FROM photos WHERE id=':id' LIMIT 1";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
$stmt->execute();
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE user=':session' LIMIT 30";
$stmth=$conn->prepare($sql1);
$stmth->bindparam(":session",$sess_uname);
$stmth->execute();
$dir="user/$sess_uname";
$count0=$stmth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count=count($count0);
$row1 = $stmth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($count>0) {
    unlink($dir/$row1['filename']);
}
 /*if (isset($_SESSION['app'])&&$_SESSION['uname']!="") {
    header("location: ../home.php?u={$_SESSION['uname']}");             
                  } else {
                      header("location: ../index.php?usernotfound?id=017");
                  }
 */
```

the ajax logic is as follows:

```
$("button.delete_photo").click(function(){

    var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
var del_attr=$(this).attr('attr');
 $.post("others/delete_photo.php",
 {id:del_id},function(data){
$("."+del_id).slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove(data);});

    }
 );   


});
```

Comment: you're missing `session_start();` in the beginning of your code. Ps. `$dir/$row1['filename']` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: but session_start is included in the dbconfig.inc.php @HawasKaPujaari and it prints fine with print_r();

Comment: Your code is designed to delete one record, but your query can return multiple. Please provide the output of var_dump($row1); That way you can first confirm your query is even retrieving data.

Comment: it gives "bool(false)" @DanBelden

Comment: That would indicate your query to fetch data is not running well, slowly step back through your code using var_dump() on the variables until you find a place the code is crashing. You can then re-post or update your question with any code blockers/confusions. I'd also recommend some new line space to pad out your code for visibility sir.

Comment: sorry about that @DanBelden

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the very beginning:

**1)**
`echo` this and see what you get? Are you getting the desired/expected name?

```
echo $session=  htmlentities($_SESSION['uname']);
```

If so, `echo` this as well:

```
$sess_uname=  stripslashes($session);
```

**2)** Similarly, if you're getting a expected result by `echo`ing from:

```
$id0=  htmlentities($_POST['id']);
```

This means your first query should work.

Now, the query below works if you have already got a expected result from **1)**

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE user=':session' LIMIT 30";
```

**3)** This is not the correct way to assign a directory.

```
$dir="user/$sess_uname";
```

Rather use the proper concatenation like:

```
$dir= "user" . "/" . $sess_uname;
```

**4)** If for all that works above, this is also incorrect. Either use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to construct absolute paths beginning with the root of your website, or else use relative paths, The line written below is the reason you're getting the `Warning: Division by zero`:

```
unlink($dir/$row1['filename']);
```

Which rather should have been:

```
unlink($dir . "/" . $row1['filename']);
```

But that is *only* if `$row1` is working, which at the moment clearly is not.

Comment: the row1 is outputting bool(false) the rest of the steps seems to be working well.

Comment: @jackal4me Ahh, _There's a fault in your query_. Check for the proper table name along with the column names `echo` your query to see what's happening and if it helped you resolve your issues, dont forget to accept my answer `;-)` cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
 unlink($dir/$row1['filename']);
```

to

```
 unlink($dir.'/'.$row1['filename']);
```

Because instead of providing directory structure, you are dividing the value.

Answer (score 0):

finally found the solution, the problem was with the sql syntax.
previously it was like:

```
$sql="DELETE FROM photos WHERE id=':id' LIMIT 1";

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE user=':session' LIMIT 30";
```

i took out the single quotes for id as it was an integer and now it works like a charm.
now my code looks like this:

```
$sql="DELETE FROM photos WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1";
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1";
```